# JMeter Webdriver Sampler it opens the IE 11 browser but won't go to the URL

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

trying to run the Jmeter selenium script, it is launching IE11 browser with some port number and blank page, not able to go to the URL.

OS: windows7
Browser: IE11

if i run the same script in eclipse working with selenium and IE11 launching correctly.

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()

Error in jmeter log:
JMeterThread: Test failed!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: session null does not exist (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 11 requires some [additional configuration](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration):

> - The IEDriverServer exectuable must be downloaded and placed in your PATH
> - On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected Mode".
> - Additionally, "Enhanced Protected Mode" must be disabled for IE 10 and higher. This option is found in the Advanced tab of the Internet Options dialog.
> - The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.
> - For Windows 10, you also need to set "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" to 100% in display settings.
> - For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`. For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`. Please note that the `FEATURE_BFCACHE` subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a DWORD value named `iexplore.exe` with the value of 0.

So double check your configuration, if you are able to run your Selenium test using other client language - you should also be able to do it from JMeter.

If you still receive errors update your question with screenshots of the [InternetExplorer Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InternetExplorerConfig/#InternetExplorer-Driver-Config) (all non-default settings) and full contents of your *jmeter.log* file.

I would also recommend checking out [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) article for the most common queries explained.